# Unregistered urls in flask logs

Tags: flask, request, url-mapping

I am running a flask application and log the `flask.request.url` of incoming requests. However, I am seeing logged urls that should not be possible since they are not defined in the routing map, aka `@app.route("...")`.

How is this possible / what could possible cause this?

Any known bugs in flask that allow request urls not defined in the routing map?

Comment: Welcome! Please, share your logs. Aren't there all 404 responses?